# Search for a value and return the entire row in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to search for a value on different sheets. This works fine, 
but the problem is that I want the value of the entire row, not just the value I'm looking for.

The code is as follows:

```
Sub SearchFolders()

    Dim xFso As Object
    Dim xFld As Object
    Dim xStrSearch As String
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xStrFile As String
    Dim xOut As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xWk As Worksheet
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xFound As Range
    Dim xStrAddress As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xUpdate As Boolean
    Dim xCount As Long
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "select folder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    xStrSearch = "searched value"
    xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xOut = Worksheets.Add
    xRow = 1
    With xOut
        .Cells(xRow, 1) = "book"
        .Cells(xRow, 2) = "sheet"
        .Cells(xRow, 3) = "cell"
        .Cells(xRow, 4) = "search value"
        Set xFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set xFld = xFso.GetFolder(xStrPath)
        xStrFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xls*")
        Do While xStrFile <> ""
            Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xStrPath & "\" & xStrFile, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
            For Each xWk In xWb.Worksheets
                Set xFound = xWk.UsedRange.Find(xStrSearch)
                If Not xFound Is Nothing Then
                    xStrAddress = xFound.Address
                End If
                Do
                    If xFound Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        xCount = xCount + 1
                        xRow = xRow + 1
                        .Cells(xRow, 1) = xWb.Name
                        .Cells(xRow, 2) = xWk.Name
                        .Cells(xRow, 3) = xFound.Address
                        .Cells(xRow, 4) = xFound.Value                       
                    End If
                    Set xFound = xWk.Cells.FindNext(After:=xFound)
                Loop While xStrAddress <> xFound.Address
            Next
            xWb.Close (False)
            xStrFile = Dir
        Loop
        .Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    MsgBox xCount & "Cells found", , "EA"
ExitHandler:
    Set xOut = Nothing
    Set xWk = Nothing
    Set xWb = Nothing
    Set xFld = Nothing
    Set xFso = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

I need this to look for a value in different books and to return the information of the entire row where the sought value was found.

Comment: what does not work as expected? do you have any errors?

Comment: @avb they said they wanted the entire row copied and not just the single value

Comment: How do you want the entire row returned?  As a `Range` object?  As an array of the `Row`'s `Value`s?  Do you want the **entire** row, or just some portion of the row (an entire row contains 16384 values, most of which will be `Empty`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my best guesses as to what you could mean by "I want the value of the entire row":

To access the entire row as a `Range` object

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = xFound.EntireRow
```

To create a variable (dimensioned `(1 To 1, 1 To 16384)`) containing the values of the entire row:

```
Dim rngValue As Variant
rngValue = xFound.EntireRow.Value
MsgBox rngValue(1, 20)  ' will display the value from column T
```

To individually access certain columns from the row:

```
MsgBox xFound.EntireRow.Cells(1, "T")  ' will display the value from column T
MsgBox xFound.EntireRow.Range("T1")    ' will display the value from column T
```

To set certain destination cells to the value from certain cells on the found row:

```
'Copy values from columns A to T from original row to columns D to W of the destination
.Cells(xRow, 4).Range("A1:T1").Value = xFound.EntireRow.Range("A1:T1").Value
```

To simply find the row number on which the find occurred:

```
MsgBox xFound.Row
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!!!!! 
with this I could solve and now works perfectly. Sorry for my english I`m from Argentina. Bye and again thank you very much!!